# Can we say that $\rho (A) = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{m \to \infty } (tr{A^m})_{}^{\frac{1}{m}}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A\in M_n$ be positive and $\rho (A) = \max \{ \left| \lambda  \right|:\lambda $ is eigenvalue of $A$$\}$.

We know that, $\rho (A) = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{m \to \infty } \left\| {{A^m}} \right\|_2^{\frac{1}{m}}$.

Can we say that $\rho (A) = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{m \to \infty } (tr{A^m})_{}^{\frac{1}{m}}$?

Comment: This isn't true. E.g. let $A=\operatorname{diag}(-1,1)$. Then $\operatorname{tr}(A^m)^{1/m}$ does not converge (its $\limsup$ is 1 and its $\liminf$ is zero).

Comment: @user1551 - Thank you. I edited this post.

Comment: I amended my original answer, making the proof more clear since we are in the case of nonnegative matrices (it's ok if one or more eigenvalues are equal to zero).

Answer (score 3):

If $\lambda_1, \dots, \lambda_n$ are the eigenvalues of $A$, then the eigenvalues of $A^p$ are $\lambda_1^p, \dots, \lambda_n^p$. For any matrix, the trace is the sum of its eigenvalues.

We have for $p\in \mathbb N$: $$(tr(A^p))^{\frac{1}{p}}= \left(\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i^p\right)^{\frac{1}{p}}= \|\Lambda\|_p,$$

where $\Lambda = (\lambda_1,\lambda_2, \dots, \lambda_n)$ is a column vector and $\|\cdot\|_m$ denotes the $p$-norm. Now, as $p \rightarrow \infty,$ we have that the $p-$norm converges to the maximum norm, i.e.

$$\lim_{p\rightarrow \infty}\|\Lambda\| = \|\Lambda\|_\infty = \max_{i=1\dots n}|\lambda_i| = \rho(A).$$

**Question**: Which parts of this proof won't work if we have negative eigenvalues, in particular if the eigenvalue with maximum modulus is negative?

Comment: I dont understand.Please more guide.

Comment: @H.S: Which part is is you dont understand? That the trace is the sum of the eigenvalues? The eigenvalues of $A^p$? The convergence of norms?

Comment: your question.-- "Which parts of this proof won't work if we have negative eigenvalues, in particular if the eigenvalue with maximum modulus is negative?" Thank you.

Comment: But, Your answer is nice.

Comment: @H.S There are several parts of the proof which wouldn't work if there were negative eigenvalues: The root of the trace doesn't need to be defined, the $p$-norm would only result in an upper estimate of the $p-th$ root of $|trA^p|$ so that also the spectral radius would only be an upper bound, and not the limit.